# how to determine if a page is checked out? Client side, using javascript?

Tags: 2013, javascript, publishing-page, check-out

I need a way to determine if a publishing page is checked out by the current user; I need this because I'd like to put a redirect, if the page is not checked out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SP.File.checkOutType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244900.aspx) gets a value that indicates how the file is checked out of a document library

### Get file checkout type via REST

```
$.ajax({url: "/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + pageUrl  + "')/checkOutType",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, 
        success: function(data) {
                  if(data.d.CheckOutType == 0) {
                        console.log('The file is checked out');
                  }
               }
});
```

### Get file checkout type via CSOM (JavaScript)

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var file = web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);
context.load(file);

context.executeQueryAsync(
     function(){
         if(file.get_checkOutType() == SP.CheckOutType.online) {
                        console.log('The file is checked out');
         }    
      },
      function(sender, args){    
          console.log(args.get_message());
      }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Client Object Model to get a reference to the file and then use the checkOutType property to see if it has been checked out.

[SP.File.checkOutType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244900.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

They're both working, thanks!

I've found another way, a little faster because it doesn't need to call the server back again, but it can only to determine if the file is checked out by the current user, not by a generic user.

I've found a way to achieve this, tested on Sharepoint 2013.

Just add the following script inside a script webpart after putting it inside the publishing page.

There's a variable called "PageState", that contains a useful field.

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var isCheckedOut = false;
        if (typeof(PageState) != "undefined" && PageState)
        {
            isCheckedOut = PageState.ItemIsCheckedOutToCurrentUser == "1";
        }
        if (!isCheckedOut)
        {
            //do redirect
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me when I embedded it on the aspx page.

Comment: Works great on a publishing page, and no need for a request to the server!